# Is it possible to disable downgrading subscriptions in App Store In App Purchase?

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, app-store, subscription

I'm currently developing an app for storing files and documents, and by default the users are able to create an account for free. However, should they want to increase the max size available for their storage, they should upgrade their account by subscribing to certain packages in the app.

My question is this: Would it be possible to disable downgrading the subscription? My app's workflow only enables user to be in their current subscription account level (whether it's free or not) or upgrade to a subscription of higher level. Ah, and I'm using Flutter for this app.

I read through the documents and best practices of implementing subscription in App Store, but I didn't find anything mentioning the way to disable downgrading the subscription.